# C# Property with variable sub properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Is it possible to create a property in C# that has a variable number of sub properties and then generate them via xml? Example below

```
Question.Name = "cake";
Question.Type = "radio";
foreach(Option option in xmloptions)
{
    Question...........
}
```

So what I am getting at is if xmloptions had 5 options on one question then 4 on the next. Could I populate those as such in the property I create to house the questions? And if so how can I enumerate them?

Forgive me if that makes no sense......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one of the properties of your `Question` class should be either a list or a dictionary:

```
public class Question {

    private List<Option> _Options = new List<Option>() 

    public List<Option> Options {
      get { return m_Options; }
    }
}
```

and then you add the options with:

```
question.Options.Add(option);
```

If each option is identified by something - like a name for example - you can use a dictionary:

```
public class Question {

    private  Dictionary<string, Option> _Options = new Dictionary<string,Option>();

    public Dictionary<string,Option> Options {
      get { return _Options; }
    }
}
```

and in this case you add the options with:

```
question.Options[name] = option;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, object>` (you could also use a more specific type than object if you always knew the type ahead of time) to store them:

```
var question = new Dictionary<string, object>();
question["Name"] = "cake";
question["Type"] = "radio";

foreach(Option option in xmloptions)
{
    question["SomeOtherProperty"] = option.SomeOtherProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the property type of Option (Question.Option) to be an arraylist.  And if you need to, you could make it a list of Question objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a dynamic object like ExpandoObject in .Net 4. You can add properties and methods dynamically.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx

You can also inherit from DynamicObject or IDynamicMetaObjectProvider but those increase in complexity significanlty.

However, try using a dictionary instead of a dynamic, it'll probably be easier on you.